# Can't change screen resolution in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: display, hdmi, display-resolution

i can not click the button in Displays to change resolution, it is gray.

Displays:

[image: Displays]

and when I use xrandr, the following message is given:

```
(base) cv@cv-MS-7B17:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1024x768 (0x1be) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
(base) cv@cv-MS-7B17:~$ xrandr --size 1600x900
Failed to change the screen configuration!
```

Does it mean there are some things wrong with my monitor?

Comment: have you tried plugging it out and in already while the computer is running? And also if it was turned off? (sometimes it helps)

Comment: v16.04 is fast approaching EOL. View [this reference](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-16-04-end-of-life) to prepare in advance to move forward. Now might seem a good time...

Comment: If this is a VM, check the host settings. If it's hardware, I'd `sudo lshw -C video` to check your video hardware is detected correctly (you are using a very old release, so it won't know about more recent hardware and I'd suggest an upgrade, as *xenial* or 16.04 reaches the end of it's *standard* support next month)